# Generate PDF in Persian with @react-pdf/renderer

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf, farsi

I have problem with displaying Persian text on a  PDF file. while rendering the component it works fine but when saving it as a PDF file it shows dummy text.

how it displays on webpage

[image]

and when downloaded

[image]

My code:

```
import font from "./IRANsans.ttf";

Font.register({
  family: "IRANSans",
  format: "truetype",
  src: font,
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    fontFamily: "IRANSans",
  },


<Document style={{ backgroundColor: "white", padding: "10px" }}>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
      <View >
        <Text>متن نوشته شده به فارسی</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
```

any solution or suggestion?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it with this Method. I used `Font.register` like this :

```
Font.register({
  family: 'IRANSans',
  fonts: [
    {
      src: IRANSansFont,
      fontWeight: 400
    }
  ]
```

})

In `src` you must `import IranSans` TTF File.

I had another problem with typescript that does not know this import and to solve it you must create a `*.d`.ts file (ex: `Fonts.d.ts` ) in TTF folder and write this code inside .ts file: declare module `'*.ttf`'.

Finally, you can use `fontFamily: 'IRANSans'` style in your code